# 'createSortHandler' is assigned a value but never used

Tags: html, typescript, material-ui, next.js, tsx

## Value assigned but never read error.

### **My function `EnhancedTableHead` within `CustomizedTables()` is throwing the following error:**

#### **Functions:**

```
export default function CustomizedTables() {
    const customization = useSelector((state: DefaultRootStateProps) => state.customization);

    function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
        const { onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort } = props;
        const createSortHandler = (property: keyof Data) => (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>) => {
            onRequestSort(event, property);
        };
    }
```

#### **Error Output:**

```
'createSortHandler' is assigned a value but never used. eslintno-unused-vars
```

#### **HTML where I am calling the function:**

```
<TableSortLabel
                                                active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                                direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                                                onClick={EnhancedTableHead.createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                                            >
```

#### **Error related to the `onClick` function call:**

```
Property 'createSortHandler' does not exist on type '(props: EnhancedTableProps) => void'.ts(2339)
```

I appreciate any feedback you can provide me in fixing this error.  Thank you.

Comment: `EnhancedTableHead` is a function, so `createSortHandler` does not exist as a property on it, which accounts for the typescript error. `createSortHandler` is neither used or returned from the `EnhancedTableHead` function, which accounts for the eslint error.

Comment: @Lioness100 Should I return createSortHandler from my EnhancedTableHead function to remedy this error?

Comment: Sure, but you'd still have to call `EnhancedTableHead` as a function and pass in props.

Comment: @Lioness100 I apologize, but could you provide me with a code example regarding what the syntax of your answer might look like?  I ask because I believe I tried this method but it did not work.  However, I want to make sure that I used the correct syntax.  Thank you.

Comment: With the code you provided, assuming you return `createSortHandler`, it would be `EnhancedTableHead(props).createSortHandler(...)`